# Is it possible to automate the TeamCity Pin Functionality on a "Run Custom Build"

Tags: teamcity

I'm using TeamCity with a build step to tag a certain build into SVN if I run a Custom Build with one of the flags set to true.

However, after this build has completed, I would like to automate TeamCity to pin the just-created custom build. Is this possible? I've read about the REST API, but I am not sure if it's the solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured it out by using the REST API instead of utilizing the plugins.

By creating a Command Line build step using the Custom Script field, you can use cURL to effectively pin builds. There might be some modifications required to pin a build that is already running.

This curl call pins the build:

```
curl -v --request PUT %teamcity.serverUrl%/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/id:%teamcity.build.id%/pin -u "TCuser:TCpass"
```

This curl call adds/edits the tags for the specific build:

```
curl -v -H "Content-Type:text/plain" -d "Deliverable" %teamcity.serverUrl%/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/id:%teamcity.build.id%/tags -u "TCuser:TCpass"
```

Also you should make sure to install/place a curl executable on the build agent so that you can call curl as a command line tool.

Answer (score 1):

REST is the only way to do that without writing java code. Or you can write a plugin which listens for buildFinished event and pins the build if it has particular property.

Comment: are there any examples on writing a plugin for that event?

Comment: TeamCity distribution contains a sample plugin with various
extensions. To get notification on build finid you need is to extend a class `BuildServerAdapter` and implement a method `buildFinished(SRunningBuild build)`. API is wrong here, it should pass `SFinishedbuild`, which has method `setPinned(boolean pinned)`. You can get `SFinishedBuild` using
`BuildHistory.findEntry(runningBuild.getBuildId())`. You can find more info [here](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/Developing+TeamCity+Plugins).

Comment: thanks, i think i will be taking the path of using a plugin. Is there somewhere where I have to write this plugin? Or can I go into a build step on TC, and write this plugin in one of the dropdown options?

Comment: well in my Custom Script Command Line build step, how would i call this method? PUT http://teamcity:8111/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/<buildLocator>/pin/ can I echo that command and it will work? and also, I am having trouble finding the buildLocator, i'be been trying bt# where # is the number from the project but that doesn't work

Comment: @neverov: Could you please provide a link to the sample plugin you are referring to...? Better yet, could you update your answer to contain a simple example class (with imports and so on) that illustrates very basically how to do (or approach) this?